# What are these two holes in the cylinder head? (Suzuki M13A engine)

Tags: suzuki, head-gasket, cylinder-head

I changed the valve cover gasket on my 2004 Suzuki Wagon R+.
The cylinder head looks like this (for reference, the engine has 201.000km):

[image]

What are the two holes I circled? They don't have anything opposite (on the rocker cover).

Close up:

[image]

[image]

The service manual doesn't have info on them:

[image]

The reason I'm asking is because the head gaskets that I could buy are different, all brands and models look like this:

[image]

And thus they don't seal the two holes in question. I wonder if I did something wrong with the change, leaving those two holes in oil.

Answer (score 1):

If the holes are not threaded and do not open to anything at the bottom of them, I'd suggest there's probably no need to worry about it. It seems to me these holes are there for some bygone reason, meaning they originally had a purpose, but are no longer used. If they were threaded, I'd suggest they were for a center set of bolts to help keep the valve cover in place. It appears the top of them are machined because it is flush with the top of the sparkplug holes (IOW: it gets machined whether it needs it or not).

Comment: Thank you. I confirm they are not treaded. Strange thing is, after a Google image search, these kind of pinholes are present on almost any Japanese engine.